# Dates and Between statement

Tags: sas

I am using SAS E.G. 7.1

I have the following code:

```
data time_dim_monthly;

    do i = 0 to 200;
        index_no = i;
        year_date = year(intnx('month','01JAN2008'd,i));
        month_date = month(intnx('month','01JAN2008'd,i));
        SOM = put(intnx('month', '01JAN2008'd, i, 'b'),date11.) ; 
        EOM = put(intnx('month', '01JAN2008'd, i, 'e'),date11.) ; 
        days_in_month = INTCK('day',intnx('month', '01JAN2008'd, i, 'b'),
                        intnx('month', '01JAN2008'd, i, 'e')); 
        output;
    end;
run;
```

followed by

```
proc sql;
    create table calendar as 
        select year_date, month_date, index_no, put(today(),date11.) as todays_dt, som, eom
            from time_dim_monthly
                where put(today(),date11.) between som and eom
/*or datepart((INTNX('month',today(),-1)) between som and eom)*/
        order by index_no
                ;
quit;
```

The output looks like this:

```
year_date   month_date  index_no    todays_dt   SOM EOM
2008    10  9   31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2008 31-OCT-2008
2009    10  21  31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2009 31-OCT-2009
2010    10  33  31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2010 31-OCT-2010
2011    10  45  31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2011 31-OCT-2011
2012    10  57  31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2012 31-OCT-2012
2013    10  69  31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2013 31-OCT-2013
2014    10  81  31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2014 31-OCT-2014
2015    10  93  31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2015 31-OCT-2015
2016    10  105 31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2016 31-OCT-2016
2017    5   112 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2017 31-MAY-2017
2017    10  117 31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2017 31-OCT-2017
2018    5   124 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2018 31-MAY-2018
2018    10  129 31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2018 31-OCT-2018
2019    5   136 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2019 31-MAY-2019
2019    10  141 31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2019 31-OCT-2019
2020    5   148 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2020 31-MAY-2020
2020    10  153 31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2020 31-OCT-2020
2021    5   160 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2021 31-MAY-2021
2021    10  165 31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2021 31-OCT-2021
2022    5   172 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2022 31-MAY-2022
2022    10  177 31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2022 31-OCT-2022
2023    5   184 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2023 31-MAY-2023
2023    10  189 31-MAY-2017 01-OCT-2023 31-OCT-2023
2024    5   196 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2024 31-MAY-2024
```

While I'd expected that it would only give me one line:

> 2017  5   112 31-MAY-2017 01-MAY-2017 31-MAY-2017

Would appreciate help in understanding why this is happening.

Thank you

Comment: EG version is (mostly) irrelevant - the relevant version is the SAS version; probably 9.4 (what EG 7.1 shipped with) though you could be using 7.1 to connect to an older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your mistake:

```
SOM = put(intnx('month', '01JAN2008'd, i, 'b'),date11.) ; 
EOM = put(intnx('month', '01JAN2008'd, i, 'e'),date11.) ; 
where put(today(),date11.) between som and eom
```

`put` creates a character variable.  You shouldn't really use `between` with character variables unless you really know what you're doing (it will compare in alphabetical order).

Use numeric variables. Get rid of the `put`.  Instead use a `format` statement to make the variables look nice, but still be numeric.

```
SOM = intnx('month', '01JAN2008'd, i, 'b') ; 
EOM = intnx('month', '01JAN2008'd, i, 'e') ; 
format som eom date11.;
```

later

```
where today() between som and eom
```